# Cannot load an image file into bitmapimage while running as shell in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, shell

I want to load an image from file into `bitmapimage` while running my application as a default shell..

following is the code i am using

```
string wallpaper = @"c:\images\wallpaper1.jpg";
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
src.BeginInit();
src.UriSource = new Uri(wallpaper, UriKind.Relative);
src.EndInit();
ImageBrush br = new ImageBrush();
br.ImageSource = src;
br.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
maingrid.Background = br;
```

i can load the image. when debugging or running as a simple application..but it force closes when i run it as a default shell.

Comment: What do you mean by _default shell_?

Comment: @dkozl by default shell i mean my application serves as an alternate shell ui for windows(default is explorer.exe).

Comment: just like smartlaunch cafe manager.....